# Css grid system

Tags: css, grid

What would be the best grid system for my app?

My app is a huge form. I will only be applying the grid to the content area because that's the only place I need it. The default content area is a section and has no left indent. We also have subsections which should be indented a bit. It can actually go down 4-5 levels of indentation. The problem is sure I could lose a grid for the indent but then you can't split 50/50 is you only have 15 grids left. I currently customized a version of 1kb grid system to handle 2 grids. 1 for sections and 1 for subsections. The 2 are different widths. I'm no sure if that's the best solution but it works.

I had a percentage based gs before but that caused problem with paddings/margins for nested grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible for us to say what is best for you. Personally, for something rather confined (ie, a big form) then I'd suggest roll your own grid that makes sense for the particulars of your product.

In my experience, the out-of-the-box grid systems (960, blueprint, etc) don't necessarily have really robust options for complex forms.

Comment: Ended up creating a custom grid system. A mix between 960gs and 1kb gs. Works nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can try my gs, Fluidable. It is based on percentages but is also nestable and has fixed gutters. http://fluidable.com

But really it sounds like you should just create your own custom solution, its not that hard :)